# Symfony2 - How to remove the Doctrine Bundle?

Tags: doctrine, symfony, bundle

I am currently working on a project using Symfony2 and I have no need for the Doctrine Bundle. I have tried to remove it on numerous occasions but I keep getting errors that break the install.

I have grep'ed for all instances of 'Doctrine' within the app directory and have commented out any reference to Doctrine in the following files:

- app/config/config.yml
- app/AppKernel.php
- app/autoload.php

I then cleared the cache (currently working in dev mode, so removed the cache/dev directory).

The Error I am currently getting is:

> Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\FileCacheReader' not
> found in
> /path/to/application/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on
> line 45

This refers to this block of code in the cache

```
/**
 * Gets the 'annotation_reader' service.
 *
 * This service is shared.
 * This method always returns the same instance of the service.
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Annotations\FileCacheReader A Doctrine\Common\Annotations\FileCacheReader instance.
 */
protected function getAnnotationReaderService()
{
    return $this->services['annotation_reader'] = new \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\FileCacheReader(new \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader(), '/path/to/application/app/cache/dev/annotations', true);
}
```

but I cannot find a way to stop this from being added to the cache, as I cannot find any settings relating to the `annotation_reader`.

Comment: My suspicion would be that it cannot actually be removed. Do you really need to remove it? Can't you just ignore it?

Comment: I suppose I could ignore it, but would prefer to only have bundles in the project that are actually being used by the project.

Comment: i agree and as S2 is built on bundles so i would have thought it should be removable. What would happen if you wanted to use a non doctrine data store.

Answer (score 5):

Symfony uses Doctrine's annotation library. You don't need Doctrine's ORM or DBAL and you can remove them. But you need annotation reader if you use annotations anywhere in your project.

EDIT: You'll have to test it on your own. I never tried it myself.

These bundles seem to use annotation reader:

- DoctrineBundle
- DoctrineAbstractBundle
- SecurityExtraBundle
- FrameworkExtraBundle
- FrameworkBundle

Note that it's probably not worth the effort. If you're not using given services they're not created.

Comment: Exactly. If you are using controller annotations, you need to keep the Doctrine Common bundle.

Comment: This is good BTW. Instead of reinventing the wheel Symfony uses something that already exists in Doctrine.

Comment: I'm not using annotations either. I might in a future project but not for this project. So the question is how do I disable annotations so the code block above isn't produced? The only mention in the config is under Framework: validation: { enable_annotations: true }. Setting this to false doesn't stop it.

Comment: I too would like an answer to this as I intend to use Propel and do not intend to use annotations.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna have a look at:
http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1

and

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/

;)